# How to use Conan in Bazel

Tags: bazel, conan

I am new in bazel and conan.
I try run conan in bazel use it https://docs.conan.io/en/1.44/integrations/build_system/bazel.html

In WORSPACE file:

```
load("//third-party/grpc:direct.bzl", "load_conan_dependencies")
```

In direct.bzl

```
load("@//conandeps:dependencies.bzl", "load_conan_dependencies")
```

conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
grpc/1.45.2

[generators]
cmake
```

When i try bazel sync
then has message:

```
ERROR: error loading package '': at /Users/a19583433/_WORK/videomix/third-party/grpc/direct.bzl:5:6: Label '//conandeps:dependencies.bzl' is invalid because 'conandeps' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '//:conandeps/dependencies.bzl'?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Conan is getting a new, more complete Bazel integration in https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/google.html, I'd recommend having a look at that. It also gained a ``conan new hello/0.1 -m=bazel_lib`` (and ``bazel_exe``) template in last release, which is a good starting point to try things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc is a little bit misleading - In short, `conandeps` is not a keyword, and you should replace `conandeps` to the subfolder that holds your conanfile.txt

e.g.,
you should have your load function like
`load("@//subfolder1:dependencies.bzl", "load_conan_dependencies")`
when you have the following folder structure

```
project
│   WORKSPACE
│   somefile.txt   
│
└───subfolder1
    │   conanfile.txt
    │   somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

It took me quite a bit of time to figure out how to get Bazel and Conan to work together even with the accepted answer here, so I want to provide some additional information that is missing from here and from the documentation that would have helped me.

First off (because it's easy to confuse) what's being discussed here is consuming Conan packages with Bazel, not producing Conan packages.

`dependencies.bzl` **is a generated file**. This file gets generated when you run `conan install` and `BazelDeps` is listed as a generator in your conanfile (.txt or .py). **You must run** `conan install` to trigger `BazelDeps` to create this file.

After running `conan install` the `dependencies.bzl` will be generated in the current working directory along with directories for each of the dependencies listed in your conan file. Each of these will have a generated BUILD file. You should not directly reference these BUILD files. As it is shown in the documentation you simply add `load("@//[your-path]:dependencies.bzl", "load_conan_dependencies")` to your WORKSPACE and now you can use the libraries from your conan file.

Example of my generated `dependencies.bzl`:

```
def load_conan_dependencies():
    
    native.new_local_repository(
        name="gtest",
        path="/conan-cache/.conan/data/gtest/1.12.1/_/_/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9",
        build_file="/workspaces/test-project/generated/third-party/gtest/BUILD",
    )
```

Example of my `WORKSPACE`:

```
load("//generated/third-party:dependencies.bzl", "load_conan_dependencies")
load_conan_dependencies()
```

Footnote:

Because we have multiple developers and we want to streamline this process, what we settled on is running `conan install` as part of a build script that then executes our regular build process. When you first run `conan install` it will pull the libraries and install them into the conan cache. After that, running the install is effectively a no-op. BazelDeps will overwrite all the generated files with the same contents, but because Bazel uses file content hashes to determine if inputs have changed, this does not result in having to rebuild anything. It just slows down the build slightly by re-running the generator.